# how to handle soap fault in wso2 out sequence

Tags: wso2, transformation, soapfault

I can't transform a SoapFault to JSON in my out sequence, please help.

This is the Soap response:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
     <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Error en consultar: LA CONSULTA NO ARROJO NINGUN RESULTADO</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <ns8:consultarFault xmlns:ns8="http://colsanitas.com/Persona/">
           <consultarFault>
              <ns7:errorCode xmlns:ns7="http://colsanitas.com/osi/comun/nofuncionales">38</ns7:errorCode>
              <ns7:errorDesc xmlns:ns7="http://colsanitas.com/osi/comun/nofuncionales">LA CONSULTA NO ARROJO NINGUN RESULTADO</ns7:errorDesc>
           </consultarFault>
        </ns8:consultarFault>
     </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
```

And this is my REST API:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="PersonaOSI" context="/persona">
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{documento}?tipo={tipo}">
    <inSequence>
        <log>
            <property name="DOCUMENTO" expression="get-property('uri.var.documento')"/>
            <property name="TIPO" expression="get-property('uri.var.tipo')"/>
        </log>
        <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:srv="http://colsanitas.com/osi/srv" xmlns:per="http://colsanitas.com/Persona/" xmlns:per1="http://colsanitas.com/osi/comun/persona" xmlns:nof="http://colsanitas.com/osi/comun/nofuncionales">
                    <soapenv:Body>
                        <per:ConsultarPersonaEnt>
                            <consultarPersonaEnt xmlns="">
                                <srv:consultaPersona>
                                    <srv:identificacion>
                                        <per1:Documento>$1</per1:Documento>
                                        <per1:TipoDocumento>$2</per1:TipoDocumento>
                                    </srv:identificacion>
                                    <srv:aseguradora>?</srv:aseguradora>
                                </srv:consultaPersona>
                            </consultarPersonaEnt>
                        </per:ConsultarPersonaEnt>
                    </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.documento')"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.tipo')"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <header name="Action" scope="default" value="http://www.colsanitas.com/Persona/consultar"/>
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="https://osiapppre02.colsanitas.com/services/PersonaOSI" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence>
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
                {"Error" : $1}
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" evaulator="xml" expression="//soapenv:Fault/faultstring"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
        <send/>
    </faultSequence>
</resource>
```

But I am getting an exception:

```
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFault
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can have the complete SOAP envelop in PayloadFactory mediator to overcome this error

E.g

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
<format>
    <Envelope>
        <Body>
          <response>
               <error>$1</error>
          </response>
        </Body>
    </Envelope>
</format>
<args>
   <arg xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" evaulator="xml" expression="//soapenv:Fault/faultstring"/>
</args>
```